# Adjusting spacing between axes label and axes boundary in matplotlib inset

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, axes, insets

I've generated a network figure and I'm adding this as an inset to a figure generated in matplotlib:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox
import numpy as np

G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=10, m=15, seed=1)
nxpos = nx.spring_layout(G, dim=3, seed=1)

nxpts = [nxpos[pt] for pt in sorted(nxpos)]
nx_lines = [(nxpts[i], nxpts[j]) for i, j in G.edges()]

# node values
values = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [30, 80, 10, 79, 70, 60, 75, 78, 65, 10],
          [1, .30, .10, .79, .70, .60, .75, .78, .65, .90]]
time = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2]  # in seconds

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], 'go-', label='line 1', lw=2)

bbox = Bbox.from_bounds(.6, 0, .5, .5)
inax = fig.add_axes(bbox, projection = '3d')

# set angle
angle = 25
inax.view_init(10, angle)

# hide axes, make transparent
inax.grid('off')
inax.set_xlabel('x', labelpad=0, loc='right')
inax.set_ylabel('y', labelpad=0, loc='top')
inax.set_zlabel('z', labelpad=0, loc='right')
inax.set_xticklabels([])
inax.set_yticklabels([])
inax.set_zticklabels([])
    
# plot 3d
seen = set()
for i, j in G.edges():
    x = np.stack((nxpos[i], nxpos[j]))
    inax.plot(*x.T, color='k')
    if i not in seen:
        inax.scatter(*x[0], color='skyblue')
        seen.add(i)
    if j not in seen:
        inax.scatter(*x[1], color = "skyblue")
        seen.add(j)

fig.show()
```

[image: Output of code block]

Tick labels have been removed so there is a lot of whitespace between the boundary box of axes and axes labels (please check the inset axes labels in the image above). To  adjust the spacing between the axes boundary box and the axes labels I tried to set `labelpad=0` in `inax.set_xlabel('x', labelpad=0, loc='right')`. But this doesn't remove the whitespace.

How do I place the labels close to the axes boundary?

Comment: you can set `labelpad` to negative values